# Quickest way to turn off the delete option in swipe to delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello fellow programmers, I know a little about the swipe to delete with table view function (have been using it a lot for the messaging part of the app), But how do I turn off the delete option that slides out after swiping left. I have done some looking but I can't find a good answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Could you please elaborate on what it is you exactly want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the user from the ability to edit or delete a UITableViewCell, you can do it by adding this delegate method to your tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        var boolToReturn:Bool = true
        if userCanEdit == true {
            boolToReturn = true
        }

        else if userCanEdit == false {
            boolToReturn = false
        }

        return boolToReturn
    }
```

In your case, you want to `return false` which means the delete or editing option will not show when you swipe the UITableViewCell